# C. Function pointer callback. Incompatibility with prototype.

Tags: c

I developed a mechanism for function callback. This is my function.

`int function_root(var1,var2, int(*callback)(), ...);` 

so if **var1=var2** then **callback(va_arg list);**

For example:

> function_root(a,b,**fun_clbck**,x,y,z);      //if a=b
> we will get this: **fun_clbk(x, y, z);**

Problem is. When my function callback have at least one argument. I get a warning **incompatibility with prototype**

I think the problem is in my function root. I declared int(*callback)() with zero parameter and once I do a callback like fun_clbck(int,int,int); it triggers that problem.

Comment: @larsmans I found a solution here , I should cast my function callback like this ----------------------------------                      
function_root(a, b, (int(*)())fun_clbk ,x,y,z);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i declared `int(*callback)()` with zero parameter

That's not true. `int(*callback)()` is not a C89/C99 prototype; it declares a function pointer to something returning `int`, without specifying types of parameters. The proper declaration for a function pointer with no arguments would be

```
int (*callback)(void)
```

> and once i do a callback like `fun_clbck(int,int,int);` it trigger that problem

Obviously. The parameter types declared for the callback function must match that in the call. Rethink your design, e.g. use a variable number of arguments:

```
int (*callback)(unsigned, ...)
```

and pass the number of actual arguments as the first parameter.

Comment: thnks for the response; but how should i write in this case the function_root callback??

Comment: `function_root(n_args, ...)` then get the actual parameters out with the macros from `<stdarg.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameters using variable argument lists (stdarg.h). see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/

something like this

EDIT:

```
template <typename T>
int mycallback(unsigned amount, ...){
  int i;
  T val;
  va_list vl;
  va_start(vl,amount);
  for (i=0;i<amount;i++){
    val+=va_arg(vl,T);
  }
  va_end(vl);
};

template <typename T> 
int function_root(int var1, int var2, int(*callback)(unsigned, ...)<T>, unsigned amount, ...){
  if (var1 == var2) 
    return callback<T>(amount, ...);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The function pointer

```
int (*callback)()
```

is a pointer to a function with an unspecified number of parameters of unspecified types that returns an `int`.

It can hold a pointer to any function that returns `int` and with a fixed number of parameters.

for example

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return 0;
} 

int (*callback)() = foo;
```

is OK.

But the number of parameters of the function has to be fixed. It cannot be variable (you cannot pass a function with a prototype with the ellipsis (...) notation).